# Prepared statement update issue

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I've started using prepared statement for my sql updates, but I seem to be getting a snag when I'm updating. The logic seems sound but I get an error whenever it goes into the update segment. I can delete or insert fine. Anywho...

```
Connection con = getDBConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

String query = "update table set int = ?, String= ? where int= ? and date= ?";
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setInt(1, var);
pstmt.setDate(2, sqlDate);
pstmt.setInt(3, intVar);
pstmt.setString(4, stringVar);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I've done all the troubleshooting I can and everything seems fine except for this, potentially.

```
Error = "A non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your string and date the wrong way round - you're calling `setDate(2, ...)` when the second parameter is in the context of "String = ?" and `setString(4, ...)` when the fourth parameter is in the context of "date = ?".

Admittedly the error you're getting is somewhat odd for that, but it's all I can see...

Comment: so, in the "pstmt.setWhatever" is the paramter value (eg. 1,2,3,4) in correlation with the query statement or the database column arrangement?

Clarify: Database has 4 columns, a b c d
Statement is set a c where b d
then, the set statements are a = 1, c = 2, b = 3, and d = 4
where normally, when setting information in the database it would be 
a = 1 b = 2 c = 3 d = 4...
If that makes sense.

Comment: @cphilpot: It correlates with the SQL - the index you specify as the first argument to `setDate` etc is the position *within your SQL*. The database column order is irrelevant here. (It would be relevant if you'd just done `INSERT INTO X VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)` - but personally I think that's a bad idea.)

Comment: That might be where I got confused. Because I have an insert statement that does correlate with the column numbers. going to try your suggestion and see if that fixes it. Just started using prepared statements today (was taught incorrectly).

Comment: Ah ha! That was it. Thanks, got confused by my insert statement.